# How to use dynamic string in eval

Tags: javascript, eval

```js
let value = 'italic';
let varname = "fontSizeTitle";
eval(varname + "=" + value);

console.log(fontSizeTitle)
```

I have a big project in which i use `eval()` to assign dynamic variables to dynamic strings. The problem here is it throws an error saying `italic is not defined` but when if i want to use value as a string but again being dynamic? how do i tell `eval()` that i want the `value` to be dynamic. Sorry for not posting my project code but its the exact scenario in here too.

Comment: Don't do that. It's an absolute nightmare to maintain and secure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Comment: @Quentin i have no other choice lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `italic` a string literal as opposed to a variable name?  If so, you must surround it with quotes in order to set it.

Your current `eval` statement does this:

```
fontSizeTitle = italic
```

This is possibly what it should be:

```
fontSizeTitle = 'italic'
```

The following code snippet will show this working:

```js
let value = 'italic';
let varname = "fontSizeTitle";
let statement = varname + "='" + value + "'";
console.log(statement);
eval(statement );

console.log(fontSizeTitle)
```

I've added the statement itself to the console log so you can see what is actually being executed.